# Change Windows Application project to XNA project?

Tags: c#, xna

Is there anyway to easily do this?  Changing the Target framework or other properties doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for more clues in the XNA Windows game project template, found in this path:

VS_INSTALLDIR\Common7\IDE\VPDExpressExtensions\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio 4.0\ProjectTemplates\XNA Game Studio 4.0

Look for the Windows Game template called *XnaWindowsGame-v4.0.zip*

A simpler way may be creating a new Windows project, and a new XNA project, and comparing the .csproj files for both projects using a text editor (.csproj is nothing but a custom XML file).

I suspect the XNA project has a few extra tags in it specifying XNA related information, but in its essence it compiles to a Windows executable, so making these changes to the Windows .csproj file should "convert" it into an XNA project.